# opencv node ImageSimilarity error batchDistance

Tags: node.js, image, opencv, compare

I'm trying to develop a function to compare two images(same size) but sometimes I'm getting the following error from opencv module.

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == src2.type() && src1.cols == src2.cols && (type == CV_32F || type == CV_8U)) in batchDistance, file /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/stat.cpp, line 2473
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/stat.cpp:2473: error: (-215) type == src2.type() && src1.cols == src2.cols && (type == CV_32F || type == CV_8U) in function batchDistance

This is an example of my code:

```
        if (basePhoto != '' && secondPhoto != '') {
        download(url2, "path/" + secondPhoto.id + ".jpg", function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Error downloading", err);
                reject(err);
            }
            cv.readImage(result, function (error, cfotob) {
                if (error) {
                    console.error("Error image-->", error);
                    reject(error);
                }
                if (cfotob.empty() || basePhoto.empty()) {
                    reject("Photo cant be empty", null);
                } else {
                    cv.ImageSimilarity(basePhoto.matrix, cfotob, function (err, dissimilarity) {
                        if (err) {                                
                            reject(err);
                        } else {                           
                            if (dissimilarity < 25.00) {
                                console.log("Those images are equal");
                                resolve(true);
                            } else {
                                //not equal
                                console.log("This image " + basePhoto.id + " is not equal to " + secondPhoto.id);
                                resolve(false);
                            }
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

I'd like to catch the error or detect which photos are causing the error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the following fix:

Before the call to cv.ImageSimilarity function I check if my photos have cols.

```
  if (basePhoto.matrix.col().length && cfotob.col().length) {
        cv.ImageSimilarity(basePhoto.matrix, cfotob, function (err, dissimilarity) {
                  ....
```